# How much time ENTITY FRAMEWORK spent to materialize query results into entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible that I can measure how much time EntityFramework spends to materialize a single object or a list of objects after being loaded from Db.

Any advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the exactly what you want. But it can be estimated. Entity framework takes several actions when executing a query, such as:

1. Metadata loading
2. View generation
3. Parameter evaluation
4. Query translation
5. Materializer generation
6. Database query execution
7. Object materialization
8. Identity lookup

But, when you execute *warm query* (second query execution) most of *loadings* and *generations* are replaced by *lookups* as below:

1. Metadata **lookup**
2. View **lookup**
3. Parameter evaluation
4. Query **lookup**
5. Materializer **lookup**
6. Database query execution
7. Object materialization
8. Identity lookup

In this case, the cost of most steps are *Low*, except:

1. Database query execution - Potentially high
2. Object materialization - Medium
3. Identity lookup - Medium.

What you can do here is *execute warm query*, calculate time it takes, then subtract query execution time from total time and divide it by 2 (because of two medium cost). Yes, I know that will be **very rough result**, but it is better from nothing :). Here is demo:

```
// Let Entity Framework to load metadata, generate views and etc.
using (TestContext context = new TestContext())
{                
    var query = context.Set<Message>().AsNoTracking();
    Message first = context
        .Set<Message>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

// Execute warm query
using (TestContext context = new TestContext())
{
    // Log the queries to be able to subtract query execution time.
    context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    var query = context.Set<Message>().AsNoTracking();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Restart();

    Message first = query.FirstOrDefault();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed {0} milliseconds.", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Then you can subtract *query execution time* (from logs) from total elapsed time and divide it by 2.

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable approach. Entity generation encompasses more than just generating CLR object. Relationship fixup also occurs (even with `AsNoTracking`, which I'd guess is a relatively costly process. It would be hard to get detailed measurements of all these steps, even if we had appropriate hooks available (which we haven't). A black-box approach is the best we can get.

Comment: Thanks for support @GertArnold )